# Open vpn blocking from Etisalat UAE

Tags: server, debian, digital-ocean, vpn, openvpn

I have developed an OpenVPN server and an open VPN app from UAE to connect a remote server...My need is to enable the WhatsApp call from UAE. But Etisalat throttling my VPN connection. I think they are throttling through Deep packet inspection technology. Anyone here to know how to block this throttling from UAE.